# Is it safe to use silicone spray on sprinkler heads that do not retract?

Tags: sprinkler-system

Is it helpful to use silicone spray on a sprinkler head that does not retract?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe if you do not spray into the water pipe. If you clean the dirt/debris out of all of the parts and spray only where needed there won't be any ill effects.

Comment: Silicon is actually good for plants. Don't know if the rest of the spray is toxic...

Comment: @stormy it is  usually a wd40 base.

Comment: I'd never spray it on plants...use silicone spray on my tools as I was told that wd40 actually attracts water. wd40 works great for fishing...it removes human smells from fish hooks/lines.  But I've heard it isn't legal, pollution I am sure...

Comment: @stormy why would someone  spray silicone on their plants anyway?

Comment: Grin...no, spraying silicon isn't at all what I meant.  But it gives plants, I've read in Shane Smith's Greenhouse Gardening, more hardiness...vague I know.  He said to get horsetail, Equisetum, dry them, powder them and add to soil. I never made the connection to silicon spray until I read this question and just commented without thinking...I am sorry! Thanks for calling me on it...

Comment: I looked this up..."Silicon has the potential to be used in the production of floriculture crops to increase flower and stem size, accelerate flowering and improve resistance to stresses including drought."  I am sure that the silicon sprays for tools are NOT beneficial. But it is one of the reasons plants do better in the garden than in a pot.